# How to create inbound rule on Windows firewall for custom service?

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall, service, windows

Service is written in C#. It is a server that requires opening port 8080 for inbound connections. It runs as Local System and has unrestricted SID (created by sc tool). If I add in Windows Firewall inbound rule for this service, port is still closed. But if I add inbound rule for all applications using port 8080, or create inbound rule for all services, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly this should be what you need.

There are two ways that services can be registered.

1. If it isn't running in a svchost container you want a *program* exclusion with your application's binary as the type.
2. If you are running within svchost the service method you outlined is what is needed.